# Is it possible to copy over an attachment to a different input using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input, user-input

I have two inputs that are the same

```
<input type="file" size="30" name="upload_file" class="form-mobile-col-1">
```

They both allow the user to upload a file.
One of the inputs is hidden and I need to copy the contents that are uploaded to the input displayed to the user over to the input that's hidden.

How can I do this using javascript/jquery?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, it is not possible to set `.files` property of `<input type="file">` element. Though you can call `File.prototype.slice()` to create a copy of the `File` object itself. Why do you need to create a copy of `File` object?

Answer (score 0):

One word: Impossibru `o´

File inputs are more limited that other inputs. Security reasons I guess.

As an addition: I can't think of any reason for that to be a good solution of something. Tell us more detailed what do you want to achieve and we could help you find a better approach.